# What do the symbols when you recruit a new unit represent?

Tags: knights-and-merchants

When you recruit units in Knights and Merchants there are symbols below the portrait of the unit you are recruiting. Although I know two of the symbols represent attack and defense, some units like the Pikeman have a third symbol. (looks like bunch of v's connected together)
What does this symbol mean?

Here is a picture:

[image: pikeman's symbols]

How do all of these symbols translate to actual combat?
If you have one defense does that mean you have to be hit one more time to die?

Comment: I would put the last part of your question into a different question. Anyway, I've never played the game, but could it be armor vs mounted units since the 'v' looks like a horseshoe.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

U symbol means attack strength against mounted units.

Pikemen/Hallebardmen have a bonus against mounted units. Their attack is quite weak against foot soldiers, but they fight very well against horse units.

Note that actual attack/defense values used by the game are encoded in the units.dat file and they change a little from those shown on units pictures. I can't recall the change at the moment, but you may as well ask a separate question about that.